# Javascript: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 XMLHttpRequest cannot load url errors on the same line

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript code which logs in to an Elo Office server and gets a document from it based on objectid which I provide and views/downloads it.

To do this I am have to use a javascript wrapper provided by elo which basically writes java code using the javascript synthax. The problem is that the .js file I am supposed to use for this causes two errors when attempting to connect to the server.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>   de.elo.ix.client.sendReceiveSync @ EloixClient.js:27477

and

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load --url i am trying to connect to here--. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
>   de.elo.ix.client.sendReceiveSync @ EloixClient.js:27477

This is my first time writing javascript so I have no idea what to do to fix it. I've been truggling with this for over two days. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Show ELO Document</title>

<!-- Include Indexserver JavaScript Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="EloixClient.js"></script>

<!-- Example code -->
<script type="text/javascript">

// Simplify namespace access
// (all ELOix symbols are member of de.elo.ix.client)
var IX = de.elo.ix.client;

// Indexserver URL
// Since cross domain requests are not supported, Indexserver must be reachable
// via the same server from where this example HTML file is loaded.

var ixUrl = "the url i am trying to connect to as string";

/**
* This function reads the object given by its ID in the element "searchTerm".
* If the object exists, it navigates the browser to its URL.
* If the object does not exist, it opens an alert box and displays the error message created by Indexserver.
*/



function Example_getDoc() {
    try {
    // Get Indexserver connection
        var connFact = new IX.IXConnFactory(ixUrl, "GetDoc", "1.0");
        var conn = connFact.create("Username", "password");
        // Read API constants
        var CONST = conn.getCONST();
        // Get object ID from HTML element
        var objId = document.getElementById("searchTerm").value;
        // Read object
        var ed = conn.ix().checkoutDoc(objId, "", CONST.EDIT_INFO.mbDocument, CONST.LOCK.NO);
        // Assing URL to download link
        document.getElementById("downloadLink").href = ed.document.docs[0].url + "&acode=attachment";
        // Assign URL to the link that shows the document in the browser
        document.getElementById("viewLink").href =ed.document.docs[0].url; // + "&acode=inline" is default
        } 
    catch (ex) {
        // Show message box with error text.
        alert(ex.toString());
        }
    finally {
        // Skip logout in this example.
        // Otherwise the document URL might not be valid when the browser loads it.
        }
};


</script>
</head>
<body>
        Object ID:<input id="searchTerm" type="text" value="&lt;objid&gt;"/>
        <input id="bnSearch" type="button" value="get"  onclick="Example_getDoc()" /><br/>
        <a href="about:blank" id="downloadLink">Download</a><br/>
        <a href="about:blank" id="viewLink">View</a><br/>
</body>
</head>
```

and here is the javascript function which throws the error

```
de.elo.ix.client.sendReceiveSync = function(url, method, jsonText) {

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    url = de.elo.ix.client.appendUrlTimestamp(url);
    req.open(method, url, false);

    var hdrs = this.getRequestHeaders();
    for (var i = 0; i < hdrs.length; i++) {
        var hdr = hdrs[i];
        req.setRequestHeader(hdr[0], hdr[1]);
    };

    req.send(jsonText);     //this line generates both errors

    if (req.status != 200) {
        var ex = de.elo.ix.client.JSException.createHttpError(req.status);
        throw ex;
    }

    var ret = req.responseText;
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: As per the message your request should contain a header of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"... I would guess the value should be the domain name of your script...

Comment: How do I add that? I'm a complete newb at this stuff

Comment: Read around the `setRequestHeader()` method already used in your code...

Comment: Fixed it, thank you. Now I get an error Unexpected token < in JSON at line 52. What does it mean?

Comment: Probably you get XML/HTML response (maybe an error) instead of JSON...

Comment: I get an HTML, which is ok because the header allows it to return an html, problem is that the html is cut off.